# OpenCV - specify format while writing image to file (cv2.imwrite)

Tags: python, image, opencv, opencv3.0

I want to save an image using opencv's `imwrite` without any extension. I know image format in `cv2.imwrite` is chosen based on the `filename` extension. Is there a way to specify the compression format while calling the function, or would I have to rename the file once created?

```
cv2.imwrite(filename, img)
[Out]: /home/travis/miniconda/conda-bld/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:459: error: (-2) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function imwrite_
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your motivation for doing this, but if you want to write a JPEG to disk without the `.JPG` extension, or a PNG file without the `.PNG` extension, you could simply do the encoding to a memory buffer and then write that to disk.

So, if I load an image like this:

```
import cv2

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
```

I should now be in the same position as you, with an image in my variable `im`.

I can now encode the image to a memory buffer, and write that memory buffer to disk without extension:

```
success, buffer = cv2.imencode(".jpg",im)
buffer.tofile('ExtensionlessFile')
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it's not possible to specify the compression of an image while saving it without extension. I would recommend to save it with extension and then use `os.rename()`:

```
import os
import cv2

filename = "image.jpg"
img = ...

cv2.imwrite(filename, img)
os.rename(filename, os.path.splitext(filename)[0])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The motivation is we can *successfully* read an image file without extension but we would *fail* in saving it using the same name. Reading an image, processing it, and saving it using the same name in other directory is a common requirement, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score -2):

you can concatenate the fileName string with a string that only specifies the extension while calling the function.

Comment: as in `cv2.imwrite(filename + '.jpg', img)` ? Image would still be saved as `filename.jpg` right? And I would have to rename it again?

Comment: you can't convert an image from an extension to another simply by renaming the file, you have to whether chosing the extension when calling cv2.imwrite function or  by doing this : 
img = cv.imread('1.png')
cv.imwrite('01.jpg',img) as an example

Comment: I don't want to convert image extensions/compression formats. I want to have an image filename without any extension, and want to specify compression format while writing the image to disk